# My custom module integration is not visible in magento 2.4 dasboard system configuration when I installed via composer

Tags: magento, magento2

I installed my custom extension via composer. I can see that vendor/vendor_name/package_name was generated on the server by composer. However, on admin panel under stores/configuration I can not see my extension.

I have configured the composer.json of the integration and we have uploaded it to packagist.com to test the installation with composer, but when running the installation and magento commands to install modules and clear cache, the integration is not visible in the magento dashboard. However if I manually upload the files by ftp, in the path app/code and run the installation commands, the module is visible on the dashboard.  I need to achieve a successful installation from composer to be able to test the uninstall process as well.
The comands that I execute after the installation via composer are:
sudo php bin/magento module:enable module_name
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

I using Magento 2.4.1

Apart from the composer.json file, is there any other file that I need to create or configure for the module to be visible on the dashboard?

I share my module.xml

```html
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Fdis_Integration" setup_version="2.0.14">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Integration"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe you can also check 'app/etc/config.php' if after 'setup:upgrade' you can see your module there and if it is enabled. Im guessing maybe in the composer approach the setup does not work properly.

Comment: @Erfan Yes, I’m checked in ‘app/etc/config.php’ after ‘setup:upgrade’ and my module is enabled:
`'Fdis_Integration' => 1,`

Thanks,